# What do you call the act of saying a word for another?

Tags: word-request

I am pretty sure there is a word for that, but I don't recall it. Like, for example, the host of a show says "My fried over here." instead of "My friend over here." What is it called?

For example:

> The host said "fried" instead of "friend". It was a ___.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a "mistake" or a "slip of the tongue". It can also be called a ["Malapropism"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malapropism) from the literary character Mrs Malaprop, (from Shreridan's *The Rivals*) who frequently made such errors in ways that were amusing to the readers.  That term is reserved for the case where the thing that is actually said is a real word, but an obviously wrong one. Your example is such a case.

The Wikipedia article linked to defines "Malapropism" as:

> An instance of speech error is called a malapropism when a word is produced which is nonsensical or ludicrous in context, yet similar in sound to what was intended.